# Change length of motion track marker trails?

Tags: tracking, movie-clip-editor, marker

I thought I had remembered there being an option to adjust the length (in frames) of the red and blue motion trails of the markers in the movie clip editor.  Does such an option exist?

Comment: Yes it does still exist somewhere in the menu top right hand menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the movie editor.

In 2.7x it is in the Marker Display panel.

[image: 2.7]

In 2.8 you can find the *Clip Display* dropdown on the top right. *Length* is at the bottom left.

[image: 2.8]